# Why is the bathroom ventilator constantly running?

Tags: mold, humidity

Recently due to an outdoor smell which is making me ill I've had to close all my windows in my small 1 bedroom flat.

I now notice the bathroom ventilator is constantly running whereas before it used to run intermittently.  I am opening my front door often for ventilation however I am in an internal block so ventilation is not very good.

I'm just wondering do ventilators run based on sensing humidity in the flat?  If I were to continue to leave the windows closed would the bathroom ventilator be sufficient to prevent any damp and mold developing, or would the ventilator and front door be sufficient?

Comment: We need a bit more info. How is it switched, manual, motion sensor? Maybe a picture of it.

Comment: It depends _entirely_ on the particular vent fan you've got installed. We used to have a simple fan that was controlled entirely by its wall switch. I replaced it with a "smart" fan with a humidity sensor built in. Now when the switch is on and the blue light is glowing, it's on "auto" mode and the fan will turn on whenever the humidity is high enough (60% RH, I believe), and turns off when the humidity drops. If the switch is flipped off & on, the yellow light goes on in the fan and the fan runs continuously until the switch is turned off.

Comment: You might want to look closely at the grill covering the vent to see if there is any manufacturer/model info there. If not, try popping the grill off to see if there's a manufacturer's sticker somewhere underneath. Once you know the model, you'll be able to find out all sorts of info about it through the modern miracle of internet search engines.

Comment: Is your vent fan controlled by a humidity sensor, or simply by turning a manual switch on/off?

Comment: Why is it acceptable (to you) to open the front door but not the windows?